# Busca dentro de resultados de busca MYSQL

Tags: mysql, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

tenho uma situação mais ou menos igual a essa:

Uma tabela com os registros, preciso fazer uma busca com duas referencias, exemplo 
select * from CARROS where concessionaria= 'VW' or veiculo='VW' AND localização ='São Paulo'

essa busca me retorna todos os carros VW e independente da localização, ele ignora a segunda condição.

eu precisaria que ele filtrasse dentro da localização "São Paulo" fizesse um segundo filtro trazendo os dados de carros ou concessionarias que eu pedi.

O meu resultado é tipo:

VW GOL SP

VW JETTA MG

ele deveria impedir esse segundo - pois está fora de SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu select está quase correto, mas sem os parenteses ele acaba fazendo o seguinte ( vou mostrar com parenteses para você entender )

```
select * from CARROS where concessionaria= 'VW' or (veiculo='VW' AND localização ='São Paulo')
```

nesse caso ele vai pegar sempre que for vw ou for a combinação dos dois, mas o que você quer é o seguinte:

```
select * from CARROS where (concessionaria= 'VW' or veiculo='VW') AND localização ='São Paulo'
```

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado. Era exatamente isso.  Definição de priorização.  Coloquei os parênteses e funcionou.

Comment: Lucas e se eu adicionar uma outra variável? , exemplo:
select * from CARROS where (concessionaria= 'VW' or veiculo='VW') AND localização ='São Paulo' and status = 'ativo'

Comment: neste ultimo caso não está filtrando pelo status, pois os resultados vem com informações que estão no banco como "Inativas"